# omega theme, file node--type.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm using the theme of Omega 3. I would like to review the layout of certain fields inside my content type "video". I made so the file: node--video.tpl.php:

```
<? php print render ($ content ['body']); ?>
```

yet even this simple statement does not work. Does anyone know the reason? No review of the design of the node with omega 3?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `node-video.tpl.php` with one dash?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I'm using a sub-theme of omega 3 (http://drupal.org/project/omega). I invite you to try.

Comment: I don't see anything in their docs indicating use of a double dash. Drupal's standard is `node-type.tpl.php` with a single dash for per-type theming. I'd imagine Omega supports it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

for better debugging, try to install [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer).

Both can be your best friends till you solve this issue.

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why it did not work. Going up: structure -> content type -> manage display, the fields that I want to print with php hidden. Putting them visible both on the "teaser" that the "default" everything works as it should.